# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292, al guardar cambios en la vista en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, laravel-5

Cuando voy a guardar los datos del horario del dentista a la base de datos, laravel me salta con este error
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect time value: '8:00 AM' for column 'morning_start' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `horarios` (`dia`, `user_id`, `active`, `morning_start`, `morning_end`, `afternoon_start`, `afternoon_end`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, 52, 1, 8:00 AM, 10:00 AM, 15:30 PM, 19:30 PM, 2022-07-30 08:35:14, 2022-07-30 08:35:14))

en la vista quiero guardar los datos del horario de las citas de la consulta de un dentista, pero al pulsar en el botón guardar me reporta ese error.

Encontré un post que decía de agregar en config/database.php timezone->'+00:00', pero nada, hice un rollback volví a migrar toda la base de datos, limpie cache y seguía dando el error

Aquí les muestro como tengo la vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el fichero editar tengo esta configuración
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El modelo lo tengo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La base de datos esta configurada de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo mi controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fichero de ruta de horario esta de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el archivo de migración estás usando un tipo de columna **TIME** el cuál tiene un formato: ***'hh:mm:ss'*** (o formato ***'hhh:mm:ss'*** para valores de horas grandes)

**'8:00 AM'** no es un formato válido de columna.

Deberías usar un tipo '***varchar***' (***string*** en laravel):

```php
$table->string('morning_start');
```